# nested filter array javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a nested filter in js
when I filter my array primary data is affected and changed but I need preliminary data to remove filters

my js code :

```
    let result = companies;
     result.map((item, i) => {212
           let rows = [...result[i].table.table_rows].filter((item3) => {
              return Object.keys(item3).some(i => item3[i][key] === value[key]);
           });
                      
           result[i].table.table_rows = [...rows];
           return result[i];
        });
      arrayFilter(result);
```

**my data is:**

```
{
  "companies": [
    {
      "company": {
        "name": "company 1"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_rows": [
          {
            "cells": {
              "product_name": "prod1",
              "pa_size": "12"
            }
          },
          {
            "cells": {
              "product_name": "prod2",
              "pa_size": "15"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "company": {
        "name": "company 2"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_rows": [
          {
            "cells": {
              "product_name": "prod2-1",
              "pa_size": "12"
            }
          },
          {
            "cells": {
              "product_name": "prod2-2",
              "pa_size": "18"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried many ways to solve this problem, but I did not get the right answer

Comment: So why do you change the original data instead of creating new one?

Comment: I updated my code, I don't change the original data

Comment: You do change the original `companies` array. The assignment `let result = companies;` does not create a new array, `result` is simply pointing at the existing `companies` array. If you want to manipulate `result` without touching `companies` then you should clone/duplicate the array, e.g.  `let result = [...companies];`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, the point I have understand that you wanted to filter the array "table_rows" located inside each companies array object? map and filter returns new array, so the solution for this is:

```
result = result.companies.map((item, i) => {
   const newItem = {...item};
   let rows = newItem .table.table_rows.filter((item3) => {
      return Object.keys(item3).some(i => item3[i][key] === value[key]);
   });
              
   newItem.table_rows = [...rows];
   return newItem ;
});
arrayFilter(result);
```

Comment: I used the code you sent, but still the original data changes